# CakePHP Basic Authentication: Auth->allow ('display') for Homepage doesnt work

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have created the Simple Authentication that is described in The Cookbook for CakePHP 2.4. I have read here that a lot of had the same problem, that cakephp persists to redirect to login page when going to the homepage. But the solution just to add

```
$this->Auth->allow('display')
```

in my PagesController doesnt work. But it persists to redirect to the login page. All other Views can be accessed without being logged in and that is the strange thing.

Here is the code:
AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar', 
    'Crud.Crud' => array(
        'actions' => array(
            // The controller action 'index' will map to the IndexCrudAction
            'index' => 'Crud.Index',
            // The controller action 'add' will map to the AddCrudAction
            'add'   => 'Crud.Add',
            // The controller action 'edit' will map to the EditCrudAction
            'edit'  => 'Crud.edit',
            // The controller action 'view' will map to the ViewCrudAction
            'view'  => 'Crud.View'
            )
        ),
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
} 

public function isAuthorized($user) {
// Admin can access every action
if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
    return true;
}

// Default deny
return false;
}

//Loading Crud Plugin
use CrudControllerTrait;
```

PagesController:

```
public function display() {
    $path = func_get_args();

    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
        $page = $path[0];
    }
    if (!empty($path[1])) {
        $subpage = $path[1];
    }
    if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
        $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
    }
    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}

    public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();


                $this->Auth->allow('display');
        }
```

Just like said, the "$this->Auth->allow method seems to work for all other views but not for the homepage.

**Edit:**
Problem solved! I've commented my "this->requestAction" out and added 'display' to the list of allowed methods and then it didnt redirect anymore! Thank you for your help! You also need to allow all included methods from your requested actions to be allowed!

Answer (score 0):

In PagesController, in beforeFilter, can you try

```
$this->Auth->allow('*');
```

?

Comment: it still redirects to the /users/login page

Comment: can you add some debugging messages to isAuthorized? Maybe that's where the problem is

Comment: I've never used debugging messages in cakephp, so i dont know exactly how to do. however, i just tried to add 'CakeLog::write('debug', 'IsAuthorized')' to the 'isAuthorized' function in AppController as well as in the UsersController. I also tried to use it in the home view as well as in the user/login view and tried to get something by adding it to the "beforeFilter" function. I have the debugkit but i dont get any message

Comment: // For CakePHP 2.1 and up
$this->Auth->allow();

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit kinda late, but for the sake of people who still works with CakePHP, this is what works for me.

Either in the PageController or the AppController (My Case), add to the allowed actions the following, i added it in the beforeFilter in AppController:

```
$this->Auth->allow(['']);
```

You can add more actions to be exclude for authorization, like my case as follow:

```
$this->Auth->allow(['', 'noaccess', 'logout', 'authorize']);
```

As this will allow all actions no matter the controller, i sugest to use specific action names, like the example of my case, where i have actions like noaccess that is the page to be redirected when security doesnt allow a user to access a page.

I also have the security validation as follow:

```
In My Case i used for this validation the $this->request->here for getting the controller/action, you can use the $this->request->getParam('controller') / $this->request->getParam('action')

$currentModule  = str_replace($currentRoot,'', $this->request->here); Deprecated, as it also includes the parameters            
$currentAction  = strtolower(str_replace(strtolower($this->request->controller).'/','', $currentModule));

//Checking for allowed actions o avoid security
if(in_array($currentAction, $this->Auth->allowedActions))
{
$isAllowedAction = true;
echo (Configure::read('debugcfg.enabled'))? "Exit because action is allowed module": '';
return false;
}
```